# Handle two workbooks at once - Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm working on a project using Apache POI in which I have to import data from a second workbook to my current workbook. I want to create a new sheet an copy data from a sheet of the second workbook. Is it possible with Apache POI?

My current code is as follows.

```
public class New {
    public static void main (String[]args) throws Exception {
        File src= new File("C:\\Users\\LS\\Desktop\\Data.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream (src);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

        //Sheet 1

        XSSFSheet sheet1= wb.getSheetAt(0);

        sheet1.getRow(1).createCell(8).setCellValue("TOTAL");

    for (int  i= 2; i <= sheet1.getLastRowNum(); i++)

        {
            sheet1.getRow(i).createCell(8).setCellFormula("SUM(B" + (i + 1) + ":H" + (i + 1) + ")");
        }

        // Sheet 2

        XSSFSheet sheet2= wb.getSheetAt(1);
        sheet2.getRow(1).createCell(8).setCellValue("TOTAL");

         for (int  j= 2; j <= sheet2.getLastRowNum(); j++)

            {
             sheet2.getRow(j).createCell(8).setCellFormula("SUM(B" + (j + 1) + ":H" + (j + 1) + ")");
            }

        //New Sheet 
        XSSFSheet sheet3 = wb.createSheet("Total Return Code Stats");
```

I need to import data to this new sheet, Sheet 3.

I've used following equation but there is a error called " C' is not a proper reference"

```
sheet3.getRow(1).createCell(0).setCellFormula("C:\\Users\\LS\\Desktop\\New folder\\[June.xls]Average Graph!$C$4");
```

Please help.

Comment: What issue/erro you are facing creating a sheet

Comment: I've created a sheet without any error. What I want is import data from a different excel file to the current file.

Comment: We are no code writing service. This is not any logical error or whatsoever

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort was shown and its simply asking for code-writing service

Comment: I've tried following method. (cross workbook) but it didn't work for me.
https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html